# Excel External Workbook Reference With Sheet Cell

Tags: excel, cell, spreadsheet

I have a reference to an external workbook in Excel, which I want to include within it a value from a cell in the active sheet:

= ' C:\path\to\excel\workbook\ [workbook_name.xlsm] ***valuefromcellincurrentsheet*** ' ! C7

Any ideas how this can be done? Doesn't seem to work in the above way as it would think its looking for a sheet name in the external workbook which is my cell ref.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

=INDIRECT("'C:\path\to\excel\workbook[workbook_name.xlsm]"&valuefromcellincurrentsheet&"'!C7")