# Excel dropdown with autoincrement values linked to the external workbook cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to make the dropdown based on the automatic change of the cell references shown in the image below:

[image]

I used the following function:

```
 =CONCATENATE("'",U3,"$C$4")
```

where the U3 cell includes the full link to the external workbook and cell C4 is the target cell in the external workbook, from where I would like to have data populated in my tab.

The INDIRECT function isn't best for this purpose, as I have to keep all documents open for displaying all the records.

Is there any way of using the link to the external workbook cell with automatic cell increment?
The link needs to autoincrement in order to match the folders in a list.

[Excel External Workbook Reference With Sheet Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63031510/excel-external-workbook-reference-with-sheet-cell)

**UPDATE:**

As per this thread:

[Referencing value in a closed Excel workbook using INDIRECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461672/referencing-value-in-a-closed-excel-workbook-using-indirect)

I used the solution:

https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-factor-12-secret-evaluate-function

where I created the new function by name manager liked shown below:

[image]

but after the following approach:

=results

or =EVALUATE(M4)

they don't work or simply throw #NAME

I found another thread:

https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/qh1153/alternative_to_using_evaluate_in_the_name_manager/

where they say about the `=Get_equation` function, but I don't know how to apply it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're stuck to VBA or PowerQuery, unfortunately. [There is at least one reference on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461672/referencing-value-in-a-closed-excel-workbook-using-indirect) with a very similar problem, and they state it is just not possible to dynamically reference closed, external files. I ignored that and a few other statements of the same ... after a couple hours tring, I've given up.

If you do want to keep digging using EVALUATE() via the Name Manager, check out the [the VBA reference for an explanation that seems to apply well](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate).

Re the name manager: when you manually provide a full path terminating in a range, the name manager doesn't require EVALUATE(). Doing that will generate the NAME error - the data has loaded from the external reference file already ... and then that non-formula string/data is passed on to EVALUATE.

Here is an example where ExternEvalConst is =EVALUATE('full path to my file'!$A$1:$A$4):

[image]

I tried quite a few different ways, but I was not able to get the Name Manager to change a concatenated string into a constant that I could expand for values. Everything chokes, as others have noted.

I suggest that, since your images show your files are under a single root folder, and you are basically just updating one field ... PowerQuery is the way to go. You set up a query to walk the folder tree, select the files/cells you want, and send the output to a table inside your active workbook. Then you refresh your data either on file load or on a timer. Your dropdown menu would refers to that query output table, and off you go. That  won't run on the web at all, though, so this method would be stuck on Excel Desktop.

I think there are plenty of people with the same problem that would like to hear you found a workaround, myself included!